# It is getting expired, will expire or will be expired?

Tags: future-tense

I want to say that someone's contract Is going to end on February 2019. 
Can I use below patterns?

> 1. It is getting expired on February 2019.
> 2. It will expire on February 2019.
> 3. It will be expired on February 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Expire" is a current condition that may refer to a future event, so it's acceptable to use the present tense:

> Her contract **expires** in February next year.

Use this instead of "getting expired", which is not idiomatic.

Otherwise you can use the future tense "will expire" or the (somewhat more awkward) participle variation "will be expired".

> Her contract **will expire** in February next year.
>
> Her contract **will be expired** in February next year.

Note that we use *in* for unspecified dates within a period, and *on* for specific dates:

> Her contract expires **on** February 2nd of next year.

[Edit] As Michael Harvey suggests, the future perfect is also an option:

> Her contract **will have expired** by February next year.

Comment: I find "Her contract will be expired in February next year." awkward and unnatural. Contracts expire (intransitive).

Comment: By then, her contract will have expired.....

Comment: "Will have expired" is better.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Actually after thinking about it, I've gone back to the original.  It's awkward, but nevertheless grammatical to say something will have some quality in the future, in this case the quality of being "expired".  I will also add your suggestion though, since it is more elegant.